# Case-insensitive search by EmailAddress (Oracle Sales Cloud REST API)

Tags: rest, oracle11g, oracle10g

Does **OSC REST API** support case insensitive search possibility?

For example there is a Contact with EmailAddress: "**P**erson@**C**ompany.com"

This contact is not found when I querying like:

```
/contacts?q=EmailAddress='person@company.com'
```

Any solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying in Release 12 of OSC, my testing from POSTMAN works fine. The Search is case-insensitive.

/crmCommonApi/resources/latest/contacts?q=EmailAddress LIKE 'Test2@Gsd.com'&fields=PartyId, PatyNumber,AccountName,EmailAddress

Response:

....

"AccountName": "Oracle_o",

"EmailAddress": "test2@gsd.com",

....

See in my above query; I have used Test2@Gsd.com while actual data is 'test2@gsd.com'. I also tried testing with 'TEST2@GSD.COM' as stated in request below, the results are as desired.

/crmCommonApi/resources/latest/contacts?q=EmailAddress='TEST2@GSD.COM'&fields=PartyId, PatyNumber,AccountName,EmailAddress